# Dialog message with Threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface

I am developing android app in which I have a login button onclick it will fetch some data from Internet in a thread and display that in next page. while it fetching data I am displaying a dialog box showin g a message "Loading...."  but when I click the button The thread getting executed in background but its not showing the dialog box :(  The page looking like it got strucked. here is the piece of code that I am using.

```
                   showdialog();

                    //**********************
                        Thread  t = new Thread(){
                        public void run(){
                            new Downloader().DownloadHandler();
                        }
                    };

                    t.start();

                    t.join();
                    _dialog.cancel();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                           startActivity(intent);   
}
public void showdialog()
 {
 _dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading.....", "Please wait, we are on job.", true);
}
```

Please share if their is any other better way to achieve the same/ or any other optimal way to show the user that content is on the way.
please let me know if their any other better.

Comment: probably due to `_dialog.cancel();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not showing due of

```
 t.join();
```

with `join` you are pausing the ui thread and make it wait until t finishes its execution. You should use another approach, for instance you could implement the delegate pattern, to inform the UI Thread, that your thread has finished its execution, and that you want to dismiss the dialog and start a new activity.